# How to use jQuery selectors on jQuery wrapped arrays

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have an array filled with artificiality created option elements, the way I create them is the following:

```
var daysArr = new Array();
for(i=1; i<=31; i++){
    daysArr.push('<option value="'+ i +'">'+ i +'</option>');
}
$(daysArr.join(''));
```

What I'm trying to do is to use a selector on this array, like that:

```
$(daysArr.join('')).find('option:lt(5)');
```

The only thing I got is an empty array, even for **.find('option');**
There is the following info in jQ documentation for **lt()** selector:

> *Select all elements at an index less than index within the matched set.*

Mine array is an index type array. 
I'll be glad if someone can tell me from where comes the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`daysArr` *is* your array of options. Trying to `find()` something in them will go down one level too deep.

It would work if you were to do something like this:

```
$('<select>' + daysArr.join('') + '</select>').find('option:lt(5)');
```

But of course a simpler way of achieving the same would be

```
daysArr.slice(0,5);
```

Comment: I'm again doing the things in the hardest way.
thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var daysArr = $('<select>');
for(i=1; i<=31; i++){
   daysArr.append('<option value="'+ i +'">'+ i +'</option>');
}

daysArr.children('option:gt(5)')
```

Comment: Actually, he's wrapping the string resulting from joining all option texts, so he'll get jQuery methods:

    $(daysArr.join(''))

Comment: jAndy your answer is useful, but it's not what I'm looking for because  I'm trying to get the options without creating an additional selector :)